# PDF creation with printsetup (in page numbers)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I want to create a PDF from a set of pages in my excel file. The pages are 210 - 218 and i already have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="PDF example.pdf", _
quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
ignoreprintareas:=False, openafterpublish:=True
End Sub
```

this currently prints the whole sheet to pdf. I know I should include something with PageSetup but how to use pages, no clue :S.

Answer (score 0):

try using below mentioned code,

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ActivePrinter = "CutePDF Writer on CPW2:" 'printer name
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=210, To:=218, Copies:=1, Collate _
:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Thank You